# Why do my issues disappear from Epic Swimlanes in JIRA?

Tags: jira, kanban, agile-project-management, agile-processes

I have issues that show up in my JIRA project's backlog page, but they disappear when my board is using Epic Swimlanes. If the board is configured to use any other swimlane option, these issues appear on the board.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been in JIRA for almost a decade. Every JIRA board using epic swimlanes is quietly hiding all issues linked to any epic that isn't included in the board filter. It's also impossible to use JQL to query for the epics associated with a set of issues so you might include them in the board, which means epic swimlanes are effectively broken for everyone (keep your spam comments advertising paid add-ons to yourself, please).

Because Atlassian makes bugfixing a popularity contest, please consider upvoting these bug tickets:

- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWSERVER-11318
- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWCLOUD-21601

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue myself. The solution I found was to edit to query to include the Epic in the board filter explicitly using JQL, and then using the sub filter to remove it again.

Seems to allow the tasks to then appear.

Comment: This is talking about a bug where the epic isn't explicitly included in the current board filter (e.g., the epic and tickets have a different assignee and you are filtering by assignee, the epic has a state not mapped on the board, etc) and the inability to dynamically query it... JQL doesn't support joining the board's filtered issues with their epics to ensure that the issues show on the board, so the only known solutions are statically filtering by epic identifiers (not scalable/sustainable) or purchasing a 3rd party addon. The risk and organizational impact of hidden tickets is high.